# Convert comma-delimited into tab-delimited using Awk

Tags: awk

Input is a CSV file;
output is tab-delimited.
using the below command -

awk 'BEGIN{FS = "," ; -v OFS = "\t" ; } {$1 = $1}1 ' input > output

input  data as below - 1/1/1900 15:45 - CSV file

output -  1/1/1900 03:45 PM - Tab delimiter file

When i convert the csv file into tab delimiter the above column changing the format from 24H format to 12H format. How can i retain the same format as source ? Please help

Comment: How is `field1` becoming `field 1` ?

Comment: For [tag:gawk] `@include "csv"` and `BEGIN { CSVMODE = 1 }` may be an option

Comment: How do you want to handle tabs inside the quoted input fields? They can't be unquoted tabs in the output or they'd break your output TSV format.

Comment: consider upvoting, downvoting and/or accepting answers that address your original question; if you wish to change the question (to include changing the inputs and outputs) then ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Using `FPAT` in `gnu-awk` you can do this:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,"]+' '{$1=$1} 1' input

field1   field 2    field3
abc "xyz,abc"   MNC
```

`FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,"]+'` sets field pattern to one of the quoted values `"..."` or anything that doesn't have `"` and `,` in it.

---

To quote each field in output use:

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,"]+' '
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      gsub(/^"?|"?$/, "\"", $i)
} 1' file

"field1"  "field2"   "field3"
"abc"     "xyz,abc"  "MNC"
```

Comment: how can i add quotes to each field in the tab delimiter output

Comment: sorry to bug you  but  i am unable to figure this out with below error- - awk -v OFS='\t' -v FPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,"]+' ' { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) gsub(/^"?|"?$/, """, $i)} 1' filepath --- system cannot find the specified path (error) File existed and able to read that

Comment: `system cannot find the specified path` simply means that input file path you are providing is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Since all fields are wrapped in double quotes, and assuming no embedded/escaped double quotes, we can use the double quote as the input field delimiter which in turn means we just need to focus on the even-numbered fields.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS="\""; OFS="\t" }
      { for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)
            printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF-1 ? ORS : OFS)
      }
' input

# or as a one-liner:

awk 'BEGIN { FS="\""; OFS="\t" } { for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i==NF-1 ? ORS : OFS) }' input
```

This generates:

```
field1  field2  field3
abc     xyz,abc MNC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mlr](https://miller.readthedocs.io)

```
mlr --c2t cat file
```

Or Ruby:

```
ruby -r csv -e 'puts CSV.parse($<.read).map{|row| row.join("\t")}' file
```

Either prints:

```
field1   field 2    field3 
abc xyz,abc MNC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS= '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(/,/,RS,$i); gsub(/,/,"\t"); gsub(RS,",")} 1' file
field1   field 2        field3
abc     xyz,abc MNC
```

See also [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Comment: Each input field is enclosed by double quotes .is this works ?

Comment: Sure but why not just try it?

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with Perl like this :

```
perl -pe 's/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/\t/g; s/"//g; $_ = uc($_) if $. == 1' input.txt | column -t
```

Input

```
"field1","field2","field3","header"
"abc","xyz,abc","MNC","freeman"
```

Output

```
FIELD1  FIELD2   FIELD3  HEADER
abc     xyz,abc  MNC     freeman
```

as you see I printed the header in uppercase letters.